# if statement with and shell script

Tags: bash, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to make a if statement where if the hour is between 13 and 23 it will set the hour back to 12.  Now below is a snippet of my shell script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOUR=$1
if [ $HOUR > 13 ] && [ $HOUR < 23 ];
then
      $HOUR=12
fi
```

Now I am getting errors when I run this script.  How can I tweak this script to get the desired conditions specified above?

Comment: Could you run it through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) and fix the issues it points out first?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `>` and `<` are redirection operators in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $HOUR -gt 13 -a $HOUR -lt 23 ]
then
    HOUR=12
fi
```

- Use -gt and -lt instead of > < (redirection operations)
- Use -a for AND in the same expression
- Fix typo `$HOURS=12` (removed $)

Comment: `-a` is considered obsolete. Use `[ "$HOUR" -gt 13 ] && [ "$HOUR" -lt 23 ]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate that expression arithmetically rather than textually.  Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOUR=$1
if (( $HOUR > 13 )) && (( $HOUR < 23 ));
then
      HOUR=12
fi
```

Comment: You can use `&&` inside: `(( $HOUR > 13 && $HOUR < 23 ))`.

Comment: And you don't need `$` inside: `(( HOUR > 13 && HOUR < 23 ))` ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use `<` or `>` in a Bash test, you need the [[[...]]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) form of test construct. HOWEVER, that does not do what you think it does. Those are lexicographical tests.

You can either use `-lt` and `-gt` for arithmetic comparisons:

```
$ H=14
$ [[ $H -gt 13 && $H -lt 23 ]]; echo $?
0
```

(`0` means True in this case...)

Or, use the [((...))](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) for arithmetic test construct. Then you can use a C style ternary assignment to test and assign in one step:

```
$ H=20
$ (( H = H>13 && H<23 ? 12 : H )); echo $H
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOUR=$1
[[ $HOUR > 13 && $HOUR < 23 ]] && HOUR=12
```